# draw arc with different arguments

Tags: python, math, pygame, geometry

I'm using Pygame to draw some shapes on the screen.
The problem is, I get those shapes from a different application, which exports a txt with the parameters of the arc, like this:

```
ARC1:
start_x=,
start_y=,
center_x=,
center_y=,
end_x=,
end=y=,
radius=,
start_angle=,
end_angle=
```

These are the parameters pygame needs to draw an arc:

surface (Surface) -- surface to draw on

color (Color or int or tuple(int, int, int, [int])) -- color to draw with, the alpha value is optional if using a tuple (RGB[A])

rect (Rect) -- rectangle to indicate the position and dimensions of the ellipse which the arc will be based on, the ellipse will be centered inside the rectangle

start_angle (float) -- start angle of the arc in radians

stop_angle (float) -- stop angle of the arc in radians

This function asks a rect, is there a way to calculate the rect with the parameters I have (from the txt) and keep its original shape and position?

Comment: `pygame.Rect(center_x-radius, center_y-radius, radius*2, radius*2)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 that'll get the full circle's bounding box, not only the arc's though?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes of course. That is what [`pygame.draw.arc`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc) requests: *"rect 
 -- rectangle to indicate the position and dimensions of the ellipse which the arc will be based on, the ellipse will be centered inside the rectangle"*

Comment: ah, right. misread the question.

Comment: Do not apply the suggestions of an answer to the question, it will make the answer useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *rect* argument of [`pygame.draw.arc`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc) specifies the bounding rectangle of the circle the arc is on:

> rect -- rectangle to indicate the position and dimensions of the ellipse which the arc will be based on, the ellipse will be centered inside the rectangle

The bounding rectangle of a circle with a given center and radius is:

```py
bounding_rect = pygame.Rect(center_x-radius, center_y-radius, radius*2, radius*2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, but the arc is not in the correct position. I'll edit the question so I can insert the print.

Comment: @luan It is not intended to edit the question in a way to make it a completely new question.In the Pygame coordinate system, the upper left corner is (0, 0). You have to consider that.

Comment: @luan Try the negative angles